# Implementing 2 buttons in 2 separate classes android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and have a basic question.

I have created one button in my BlockIdActivity class which extends from  ActionBarActivity and implements OnClickListener() for that button. I wanted to create a new class which also extends from  ActionBarActivity with a separate button and which also implements OnClickListener(). The reason i want to do this is to separate the logic implemented by each button in separate files.

Both of these buttons use the same layout or in other words they are on the same page. Is this possible? If not do i have to implement the second button in the BlockIdActivity as well?

My button in the BlockIdActivity.java works fine.I have implemented my second button in a second class ScanWifi.java and it should show that the button was pressed. I make use of a toast here. I donot get any compilation errors. However i dont see my toast when i actually press the button. Here is content of ScanWifi.java file :

```
public class ScanWifi extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button mScanWifiButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_block_id);

    mScanWifiButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ScanWifiButton);
    mScanWifiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ScanWifi.this,
                    R.string.ScanWifi_toast,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

});

}
```

}

Content of strings.xml file are :

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">SnifferTrain</string>
    <string name="BlockId">BlockId</string>
    <string name="ScanWifi">ScanWifi</string>
    <string name="ScanWifi_toast">ScanWifi Button Pressed</string>
    <string name="negative_blockid_toast">Block Id Field Cannot Be Less Than 1 or Empty.Setting BlockID To 1</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

If my ScanWifi class can indeed extend ActionBarActivity then why is the toast not showing when i press the ScanWifiButton? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The reason i want to do this is to separate the logic implemented by
>   each button in separate files.

Yes, you can create a new `activity` to achieve this, since the `onClick` method is difference - means, the buttons do different things.

However, it is possible to do different things with a `button` using simple `if-else` logic. Example :

I have an `activity` with "save" button. `If` the data is already in the `SQLite`, i will update the data in the onCLick, `else` the data will be inserted to he SQLite in the onCLick.

The point is, it really depends what you want to do and what do you prefer. One button to do different things will create a long and more complex code in an activity class.